# Getting rid of Dagger 2 warning "Generating a MembersInjector"

Tags: java, dagger, dagger-2

Given the following classes

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    @Inject SomeDependency someDependency;
}

class SomeClass extends AbstractClass {
    @Inject AnotherDependency anotherDepenency;

    public void onCreate() {
        component = // Get component instance somehow
        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

in Dagger 2 when injecting dependencies into a class which extends from an abstract base class which also contains dependencies, Dagger shows a warning of the kind `Generating a MembersInjector for AbstractClass. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.` during compilation.

However if I override/implement `onCreate()` in `AbstractClass` and call the dependency injection there, too, the dependency `someDependency` will be injected twice which might lead to unexpected behaviour. Once in `onCreate()` of `AbstractClass` and once in `onCreate()` of `SomeClass`.

What is the best solution to get rid of this warning while preventing duplicate injection of dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [Dagger 2.9](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.9) these warnings are off by default.

Answer (score 1):

Solution could be:  define onCreate() in Abstract class only

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible since dependencies declared in the subclass cannot be injected from the abstract class in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Is it in documentation?  Or did you check dagger sources?   I do not see why it shall be impossible.  My own small DI library does this wothout problems ( in case you need vies and properties injected, you are welcome: https://github.com/ko5tik/andject/blob/master/src/main/java/de/pribluda/android/andject/BaseInjector.java )

Comment: Dagger 2 generates the code for dependency injection during compile time. Thus injecting dependencies into a subclass from a superclass would require Dagger to perform an instance check, since multiple classes with different dependencies might extend from the superclass. I doubt that Dagger is capable of this nor that it's desired by the architects to perform these checks.